# eloquent: filter and sort model by computed attribute in a related model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have these models:

```
Product (id, sn, shop_id)
Shop (id, name, latitude, longitude)
```

How to get list of products sorted by distance where:

```
distance(latitude, longitude, $request->query('lat'), $request->query('lon')) < $request->query('rad')
```

And how to append distance to the result?

Answer (score 1):

Use `orderByRaw()` with `join`:

```php
Product::join('Shop', 'Shop.id', '=', 'Product.shop_id')
       ->select('Product.*')
       ->orderByRaw('distance(latitude, longitude, ?, ? < ?', [$request->query('lat'), $request->query('lon')), $request->query('rad')])
```